# setting custom min/max value of y-axis on bar charts in echarts-for-react makes the bars go outside limits

Tags: javascript, echarts

i am using echarts-for-react and trying to create a stacked bar chart and a line chart also.
My problem is i want to give the minimum on y-axis as 0 but maximum as either the addition of maximum of two array(representing two bar charts data).

But the bar chart height goes outside the grid.
I found a similar question and some solution also on github issues::
but i dont know how to use that for react version.
here is the github issue link.

Please help.
https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/8841

Mu config::

```
const getMixedChartOption = () => ({
    tooltip: {
      show: true,
      trigger: "axis",
      axisPointer: { type: "none" },
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      orient: "horizontal",
      top: "-28px",
      left: "40px",
      textStyle: {
        lineHeight: 60,
      },
      data: ["Paid", "Pending", "Visits"],
    },
    grid: {
      top: 38,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      borderColor: "black",
    },
    xAxis: [
      {
        type: "category",
        axisTick: {
          show: true,
        },
        boundaryGap: true,
        data: from && to && getDates(from, to),
      },
    ],
    yAxis: [
      {
        show: false,
        type: "value",
        name: "bar",
        min: 0,
        max:
          pending.length > 0
            ? Math.max(...pending) + Math.max(...count)
            : Math.max(...count),
        interval: 50,
        axisLabel: {
          formatter: "{value}",
        },
      },
      {
        show: false,
        type: "value",
        name: "line",
        min: 0,
        max: Math.max(...dailyVisits),
        axisLabel: {
          formatter: "{value}",
        },
      },
    ],
    series: [
      {
        name: "Paid",
        type: "bar",
        stack: "A",
        color: "#95b200",
        barWidth: "26",
        data: paid && [...paid],
      },
      {
        name: "Pending",
        type: "bar",
        stack: "A",
        color: "#ffeb3b",
        barWidth: "26",
        data: pending && [...pending],
      },
      {
        name: "Visits",
        type: "line",
        label: { show: false, position: "center", color: "red" },
        color: "#4A90E2",
        showSymbol: false,
        yAxisIndex: 1,
        data: dailyVisits && [...dailyVisits, 0],
      },
    ],
  });
```

Here the vertical charts are touched with one other and the height of each one is same irrespective of value.
I am attaching the image of unexpected results as ::
[image]